# how to preserve data once loaded for future use in angular9 app?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an `angular` app in which `categories` loads on `home` page. So i call `getCategories()` function on `ngOnInit` so whenever `home` page loads so all categories are fetched from db and displaying on `home` page. This works fine. But problem here is that when i go to any `categories` specific page by clicking `category` name from `home` page so it navigates use to that category page. But when i again come back to home page so again it fetches all categories form db and render on home page. So in conclusion problem is that if user loads home page once and after loading home page once how much time it will visits home page so app makes that number of `http` request each time. So my question here is that is there any technique or a way to get rid of this multiple repeated `http Get` calls? Like is there any way that if user loads `home` page once so we preserve that data any where in some way and then when user again come back to home page from any where so it fetches data from our `local scope` not from db` again?

Comment: Extract your code that sends the http request into a service. Do your request there and save the resulting observable to a class member. Use `shareReplay(1)` to make sure the request is only done once.

Comment: can you mention any article or example of your approach?

Comment: I answered with a minimal example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Components` will be destroyed when you navigate away, you have to preserve the data in a more global way. `Services` that are provided in root are the way to go in Angular. That could look something like this:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MyRequestService {
   private myRequest?:Observable<MyResponseType>;
   
   constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) {}

   // Call this method whenever you want to access the "cached" request
   public doRequest():Observable<MyResponseType> {
      // only create a new request if you don't already have one stored
      if (!this.myRequest) {
          // save your request
          this.myRequest = this.httpClient.get('http://someurl.de').pipe(
             // Share the result - else every .subscribe will create another request, which you don't want
             shareReplay(1)
          )
      }
      // return the saved request
      return this.myRequest;
   }
}
```

And in your Component just call this method instead of doing the request there.

```
@Component({ /*...*/ })
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   public myData?:MyResponseType;

   constructor(private myRequestService:MyRequestService) {}

   public ngOnInit():void {
      // Use your service to make the request - obviously, you can alternatively store the
      // observable instead of subscribing here and use the 'async' pipe on your template instead
      this.myRequestService.doRequest()
         .subscribe(myData => this.myData = myData);
   }
}
```

Comment: great. I got your point now. Thanx for your guidance. :)

Comment: You're very welcome - glad it helped :)

Comment: can i use this approach to each frequently called api? is this best practice?

Comment: You can use this approach for each API. Depending on your requirements, you might need to make this more sophisticated - e.g. by adding a flag you can use to force a new request. This is a common practice in angular. If this is the best depends on your architecture. If you are using a State Management Library like `NGXS` or `NGRX`, there are better approaches. But all boil down to caching the result and using the cached value afterwards.

Comment: In a bigger project I'm currently working on I wrapped this approach in a custom decorator - that's also something you could explore.

Comment: great. Will explore this custom decorator approach. Thanks for your suggestions :)